# subtraction of binary numbers in a linked list c++

Tags: c++

Hi new to posting but a long time follower. I have been working on a project for quite sometime now and i can not for the life of me figure out how to implement the subtraction operator of two binary numbers in a linked list. The program will take in an integer and convert it to binary then add, subtract, and multiply the binary numbers then return the result.

So i have the addition operator done, (this works fine just wanted to show how i was doing my main cpp.)

**addition**

```
Binary operator+(const Binary &b1, const Binary &b2){
Binary newBinary = Binary();
unsigned iMax = b1.get_degree();
if (iMax < b2.get_degree()){
    iMax = b2.get_degree();
}
//carry bit
unsigned bCarry = 0;
//traverse the list for each bit b1 and b2, highest degree
for (unsigned i = 0; i <= iMax; ++i){
    unsigned sum = b1.get_bit(i) + b2.get_bit(i) + bCarry;

    //determine if there is new carry
    if (sum >= 2){
        bCarry = 1;
        sum -= 2;
    }
    else bCarry = 0;
    if (1 == sum){
        newBinary.set_bit(1, i);
    }
}
//handle extra carry bit    
if (1 == bCarry){
    newBinary.set_bit(1, iMax + 1);
    return newBinary;
}
```

}

addition works fine and i tried to take what addition does and apply it to the subtraction operator but i keep on hitting a wall lol

**subtraction:**

```
Binary operator-(const Binary &b1, const Binary &b2){
Binary newBinary = Binary();
unsigned iMax = b1.get_degree();
Binary switchNode = Binary();
int cutoffBit = b1.get_degree();

if (iMax < b2.get_degree()){
    iMax = b2.get_degree();
}

//swtich the bits of b2 by switching them from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0
//then add 1 to b2
for (unsigned i = 0; i < cutoffBit; i++){
    if (b2.get_bit(i) == 0){
        switchNode.set_bit(1, i);
    }
    else if (b2.get_bit(i) == 1){
        switchNode.set_bit(0, i-1);
    }
} 

cout << switchNode; cout << "\t switchNode";
cout << "\n";
cout << b2; cout<< "\t b2";

unsigned bCarry = 0;
//sub the two binary numbers.
for (unsigned i = 0; i <= iMax; ++i){
    unsigned sub = b1.get_bit(i) + b2.get_bit(i);

    if (sub >= 0){
        bCarry = 0;
        sub -= 1;
    }
    else bCarry = 1;
    if (1 == sub){
        switchNode.set_bit(1, i);
    }
}
//handles the drop bit
if (1 == bCarry){
    switchNode.set_bit(1, iMax - 1);
    return switchNode - 1;
}
cout << "\n";
cout << switchNode; cout << "\t switch node";
```

i was trying to do some debugging with my couts so that why those are there.. so any help in pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

-Jason

Comment: Please give some explanation as to where/how it is going wrong.

Comment: sorry ya i should have given more information lol.. its not subtraction right i believe.. i can get it close, the result it should output from supplied input is 11100..but i keep getting 111000, im not sure how to drop off the last bit (like 2's complement)

Comment: i just feel like my implementation is all wrong as well lol

Comment: Try to focus first on how you would do a bit-by-bit subtraction. What should a resulting bit (and the resulting borrow-carry) be given b1.get_bit(i), b2.get_bit(i), and the borrow-carry that resulted from already procesed bits?

Comment: Since you have already written addition code you can juat convert one of the 2 numbers to 2's compliment and use addition code to subtract. Apply 2's compliment on the result again to get actual binary result!

Comment: @Abhi: a-b = a+(-b). I think 2's complement could be applied just once  unless you calculate a-b as -((-a)+b).

Comment: @Alix0r: Stating the expected & actual output is a start, but isn't terribly informative without the "supplied input" lol

Comment: For one thing, please indent your code. I'm almost sure that some parts of your function are missing, which would then become obvious. That said, I think that you are in particular missing return statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2's complement code ("flip the bits and add 1") does not appear to do what it claims to do.  For example, if bit 0 is a 1, it will try to set bit -1!